# php artisan serve failing

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

Whenever I try to run the command, I get this.
I'm trying to open a Laravel mix project into the development server

```
C:\laragon\www\feudal>php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:11 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8001
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:11 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8001 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8002
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:12 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8002 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8003
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:12 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8003 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8004
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:13 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8004 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8005
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:13 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8005 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8006
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:14 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8006 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8007
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:14 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8007 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8008
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:15 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8008 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8009
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:15 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8009 (reason: ?)
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8010
[Wed Oct 14 11:11:16 2020] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8010 (reason: ?)
```

Comment: Be sure that you have the correct permissions to run a PHP server

Comment: A couple things you could try: 1) `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`; 2) `php -i` find and edit `variables_order` in `php.ini` to `variables_order = "GPCS"` 3) maybe something to do with [UAC blocking it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-overview) 4) use another php server as an alternative to `artisan serve`: `php -S localhost:8000 -t public`

Answer (score 1):

My `php.ini` had a setting of

```php
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

I removed the "E" and returned the setting to its default:

```php
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

The change suggested by Patrick in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356428/php-artisan-serve-failing/66135221#comment113801805_64356428) fixed the error:
Here is the error:

> "[Wed Feb 10 13:07:11 2021] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8010 (reason: ?)"

After making the changes:

> "[Wed Feb 10 13:10:22 2021] PHP 7.4.14 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started"